# Filter a generic list based on another list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a generic list which needs to be filter based on another list (say, `List<string>`).

```
public class Model
{
  public string ID { get; set;}
  public string Make { get; set;}
}

List<Model> lstModel = new List<Model>();
```

And the lstModel is as follows

```
 ID      Make
----    -----------
 5       MARUTI
 4       BENZ
 3       HYUNDAI
 2       HONDA
 1       TOYOTA
```

And i have another list which contains only car makers,ie

```
List<string> lstMakers = new List<string>() {"MARUTI", "HONDA"};
```

1) I need to filter lstModel which contains only items in lstMakers.
         The output would be

```
 ID      Make
----    -----------
 5       MARUTI
 2       HONDA
```

2) Based on output (1), need another list of ids with 1 increment to each item in descending order, 
   The output would be `List<int>` ie,

```
  6
  5
  3
  2
```

Note: Using lambda expression / linq is more preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Join` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
var models = from maker in lstMakers
             join model in lstModel
             on maker equals model.Make
             select model;
List<int> result = models
    .Select(m => int.Parse(m.ID) + 1)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .ToList();
```

However, this selects two `ints` since only two models match. Your result contains 4 `ints`. I assume that your result is not related to your sample, is it?

> but i need both the item and its incremental value,...

Now it's clear, use `Enumerable.SelectMany` with an array:

```
List<int> result = models
    .Select(m => int.Parse(m.ID))
    .SelectMany(id => new int[]{ id, id + 1 })
    .OrderByDescending(id => id)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Adding to your second lambda expression,

.Concat(models.Select(x=>int.Parse(x))) after Select statement gives both the results i expected.

Please correct the lambda according to that.

Courtesy to @Christos Paisios

Comment: @SanoojVS: use `SelectMany`, i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

1 )

```
var list1 = lst.Where(x=>lstMakers.Contains(x.Make)).ToList();
```

2)

```
var list2 = list1.Select(x=>int.Parse(x.ID)+1)
                 .Concat(list1.Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
                 .OrderByDescending(x=>x)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Regarding 1st output:
   Instead of 'Contains', is it possible x=>lstMakers.Equals(x.Make)

Regarding 2nd output:
    It returns only the incremental values, but i need both the item and its incremental value, so as per example i'll get 6,5,3,2. here 5 and 2 is the original item and 6 and 3 is its incremental value. So totally 4 items.

Comment: No it isn't possible, because when you call lstMakers.Equals(x.Make) you should pass to the Equals a parameter of type List<string> like the type of lstMakers. Please check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Regarding 2nd output: It returns only the incremental values, but i need both the item and its incremental value, so as per example i'll get 6,5,3,2. here 5 and 2 is the original item and 6 and 3 is its incremental value. So totally 4 items.

Comment: Try the second version, I just wrote and please let me know.

Comment: I understand the piece of code while debugging it on fresh day. Its fine. Also i did an up-vote to your answer as i already marked the other one as accepted answer. :). Both answers give the same result as i expected.